# Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I keep getting a runtime error 1004 when I try to run this code. I tried debugging by running to cursor and it seems like the error comes up when first line that offsets the active cell and enters a value in column D. I'm new to VBA and I am not sure how to fully debug this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Categorize()

Dim RN As Integer

'Find the number of used rows in the sheet
 RN = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count

   'Loop for all the cells in the column

   For Each Cell In Range("B2", "B" & RN)

      'If value in column B = "VIRGIN MOBILE", categorize expense as phone bill
      If Cell.Value = "TS-VIRGIN" & " " & "MOBILE" & " " & "CLIENT" & " " & "ID" & " " & "14" & " " & "DIG" Then

         'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Phone" & " " & "Bill"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "WALMART" & " " & "STORE" & " " & "#1097" & "      " & "CALGA" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Groceries"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "INTERAC" & " " & "E-TRANSFER" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Income"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "FPOS" & " " & "LOBLAWS" & " " & "CITY" & " " & "MARKET" & " " & "CALGA" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Groceries"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "INVESTMENT" & " " & "PURCHASE" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Investments"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "OPOS" & " " & "AMZN" & " " & "Mktp" & " " & "CA" & "        " & "WWW.A" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Personal" & " " & "Shopping"
    
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "FPOS" & " " & "ZEE" & " " & "CUTS" & " " & "LTD." & "       " & "CALGA" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Personal" & " " & "Shopping"

                
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = " " Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Income"
         
    ElseIf Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "MB-EMAIL" & " " & "MONEY" & " " & "TRF" Then
    
        'Write in category into column D
         Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Income"
         
    Else
    
        'Write in category into column D
       Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Miscellaneous"
    

      End If

   Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows do you have, I'd change `Dim RN as Integer` to `...as Long` FYI.

Comment: The UsedRange function is supposed to find that but currently it's 31 and I'll try that out! Thank you

Comment: Oh, also which sheet is the active sheet when this runs? Sheets(2) provides the last row count but the other ranges are all run on whatever the active sheet is. Also, what is LSearchRow

Comment: Oh I see. Everything should be run on Sheets(2). Would I have to enter Sheets(2) in the For statement in front of Cell?

Comment: Look up how to use the `With` statement for making sure everything refers to the right sheet.

Comment: Will try that. Thank you Batman